# Liferay 6.1 <liferay-ui:input-repeat> tag

Tags: user-interface, liferay

Does anyone knows what this tags is used for? Liferay documentation lacks of informations.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the tag is used in the scheduling view for having the repeat interval of the scheduler it is used only in input-scheduler tag that is used in setting the publishing date for staged site

[image]